# What can I change in this jQuery plugin to include sorting on table rows which are hidden

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting, sorttable.js

After mucking around with various tablesorting jQuery plugins, I came accross one which works perfectly in that it meets the following requirements :

- Sorts dates properly
- Sorts numbers properly
- Sorts words of numbers (eg: One, Two, Three) properly
- It sorts in a DOM aware manner. This means that if you update the contents of a table cell, when you click the table header to sort on that column it recognizes the new value instead of sorting on what it was when the page was first loaded. (this feature was especially difficult to find as the popular tablesorters don't recognize changes at runtime when sorting)

The only issue I am having, is that it seems to only sort the rows which are visible. I would like for it to sort the entire table, not just the visible ones,  while keeping all the above features in tact (esp the DOM aware portion) as this will be used on a table where the data may be updated by the user, and subsequently sorted.

I will be open-sourcing this jQuery plugin so I have no issues sharing the code here. The jQuery code here is mine, and the plugin I am using for the sort portion is here: [http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/).

The following code demonstrates the issue. You can click on any of the cells to get an edit inline and can make changes to the DOM portion this way.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.tables = function(options) {

    var settings = $.extend({
      page: 0,
      pageCount: 10,
    }, options);

    $thead = this.find('thead');
    $tbody = this.find('tbody');
    $tfoot = this.find('tfoot > tr > td').attr('colspan', $tbody.find('tr')[0].cells.length);

    var align = '';
    for (var content_align = 0; content_align < $thead.find('tr')[0].cells.length; content_align++) {
      align = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[content_align]).attr('data-align');
      if (align === undefined) {

      } else {
        $tbody.find('tr > td:nth-child(' + (content_align + 1) + ')').each(function() {
          $(this).addClass(align);
        });
      }
    }

    var numRows = $tbody.find('tr').length;
    var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / settings.pageCount);

    this.bind('repaginate', function() {
      $tbody.find('tr').removeClass('visible').slice(settings.page * settings.pageCount, (settings.page + 1) * settings.pageCount).addClass('visible');
    });
    this.trigger('repaginate');

    $tfoot.find('td').html('');
    for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
      $('<a></a>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
        newPage: page
      }, function(event) {
        settings.page = event.data['newPage'];
        $(this).trigger('repaginate');
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
        if (options.pageChanged !== undefined) {
          options.pageChanged(this);
        }
      }).appendTo($tfoot); //.addClass('clickable');
    }

    $tbody.find('td').click(function() {
      if (options.cellClick !== undefined) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('editing') == false) {
          var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
          var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent())

          var type = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-type');
          var typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values');
          var align = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-align');

          console.log(type);

          $(this).addClass('editing');
          options.cellClick(this, true, col, row);
          switch (type) {
            case 'text':
              $(this).html('<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
              $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value'));
              });
              break;
            case 'textarea':
              _html = $(this).html();
              $(this).html('<textarea type="text">' + $(this).html().replace(/\<br\\?>/g, "\n") + '</textarea>');
              $(this).find('textarea').focus().blur(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value').replace(/\n/g, "<br>"));
              });
              break;
            case 'number':
              $(this).html('<input type="number" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
              $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value'));
              });
              break;
            case 'currency':
              $(this).html('<input type="currency" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
              $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function() {
                $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value'));
              });
              break;
            case 'select':
              if (typevalues === undefined) {
                console.log('You must define both \'data-type\' and \'data-values\' for select elements. \'data-values\' should be a comma delimited array of the items to be displayed in the drop-down');
              } else {
                typevalues = typevalues.split(',');
                _html = '<select>';
                for (var i = 0; i < typevalues.length; i++) {
                  if (typevalues[i] == $(this).text()) {
                    _html = _html + '<option value="' + typevalues[i] + '" selected>' + typevalues[i] + '</option>';
                  } else {
                    _html = _html + '<option value="' + typevalues[i] + '">' + typevalues[i] + '</option>';
                  }
                }
                _html = _html + '</select>';
                $(this).html(_html);
                $(this).find('select').focus().change(function() {
                  $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                  options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                  $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value'));
                }).blur(function() {
                  $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                  options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                  $(this).parent().html($(this).prop('value'));
                });
              }
              break;
            case 'checkbox':
              if (typevalues === undefined) {
                $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values', 'T,F');
                typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values');
                console.log('You can define the \'data-values\' parameter for checkbox elements. \'data-values\' should be a comma delimited array of two items. The first item is the \'checked\' value, and the second item is the \'unchecked\' value. Defaults to \'T,F\'');
              }
              typevalues = typevalues.split(',');
              _html = '';
              if (typevalues[0] == $(this).text()) {
                _html = '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
              } else {
                _html = '<input type="checkbox">';
              }
              $(this).html(_html);
              $(this).find('input').focus().click(function() {
                  $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                  options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                  typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values').split(',');
                  if (this.checked) {
                    $(this).parent().html(typevalues[0]);
                  } else {
                    $(this).parent().html(typevalues[1]);
                  }
                })
                .blur(function() {
                  $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
                  options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
                  typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values').split(',');
                  if (this.checked) {
                    $(this).parent().html(typevalues[0]);
                  } else {
                    $(this).parent().html(typevalues[1]);
                  }
                });
              break;
          }
        }
      }
    })

    this.addClass('sortable');

    $tfoot.find('a:first-child').addClass('active');

    return this;
  };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
:root {
  --tables-even-color: #CDEDF7;
  --tables-odd-color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
/* Header */

.tables thead > tr {
  background: #3E8096;
  color: #CDEDF7;
}
.tables thead > tr > td {
  padding: 4px;
  padding-left: 8px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
.tables thead > tr > td:hover {
  background: #CDEDF7 !important;
  color: #3E8096 !important;
}
/* Footer */

.tables tfoot > tr {
  background: #3E8096;
  color: #CDEDF7;
}
.tables tfoot > tr > td > a {
  border: 1px solid #3E8096;
  padding: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tables tfoot > tr > td > a:hover {
  border: 1px solid #CDEDF7;
}
.tables tfoot > tr > td > a.active {
  background: #CDEDF7;
  color: #3E8096;
}
/* Rows */

.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #CDEDF7;
  color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(even):hover {
  background: #18EAF5;
  color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #90C3D4;
  color: #CDEDF7;
}
.tables tbody > tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
  background: #18EAF5;
  color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables tbody > tr {
  display: none;
}
.tables tbody > tr.visible {
  display: table-row !important;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td {
  padding: 5px;
  cursor: default;
}
/* Cell Content */

.tables tbody > tr > td.center {
  text-align: center;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td.center > input {
  text-align: center;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td.center > textarea {
  text-align: center;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td.right {
  text-align: right;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td.right > input {
  text-align: right;
}
.tables tbody > tr > td.right > textarea {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.tables.css">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $table = $('.tables').tables({
        pageChanged: function(item) {
          console.log($(item).text());
        },
        cellClick: function(item, focused, column, row) {
          console.log('COLUMN: ' + column + ', ROW: ' + row);
        }
      });

    })
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <table class="tables">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td data-type="textarea">Column 1</td>
        <td data-type="checkbox" data-align="center">Column 2</td>
        <td data-type="select" data-values="Apples,Oranges,Bananas">Column 3</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>aa</td>
        <td>ab</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>ac</td>
        <td>ad</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>bb
          <br>ccc<b>newline</b>
        </td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>aaa</td>
        <td>T</td>
        <td>Apples</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>bbccc</td>
        <td>F</td>
        <td>Oranges</td>
      </tr>

    </tbody>

    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="1"></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Bonus:  If you can figure out how to correct the css alternating row colors after sort, that would be awesome (without adding something to each TD... basically, just 'refresh' the css somehow)

Answer (score 0):

Figured out how to do the sort in DOM while being aware of any changes made to underlying elements, however I still am unable to revert the sorting back to the original order (unsorted).

Following is what I have come up with so far:

```js
(function ( $ ) {
 $.fn.tables = function( options ) {
  
  var settings = $.extend({
   page: 0,
   pageCount: 10,
  }, options );

  this.addClass('sortable');
  
  $thead = this.find('thead');
  $tbody = this.find('tbody');
  $tfoot = this.find('tfoot > tr > td').attr('colspan', $tbody.find('tr')[0].cells.length);

  var align = '';
  for(var content_align = 0; content_align < $thead.find('tr')[0].cells.length; content_align++) {
   align = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[content_align]).attr('data-align');
   if(align === undefined) {

   } else {
    $tbody.find('tr > td:nth-child(' + (content_align + 1) + ')').each(function(){
     $(this).addClass(align);
    });
   }
  }
  
  var numRows = $tbody.find('tr').length;
  var numPages = Math.ceil(numRows / settings.pageCount);

  this.bind('repaginate', function() {
   $tbody.find('tr').removeClass('visible').slice(settings.page * settings.pageCount, (settings.page + 1) * settings.pageCount).addClass('visible');
  });
  this.trigger('repaginate');

  $thead.find('tr > td').click(function() {
   var rows = $tbody.find('tr').get();
   var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
   col++;

   if($(this).hasClass('desc')) {
    $(this).removeClass('desc');
   }
   
   if($(this).hasClass('asc')) {
    $(this).removeClass('asc').addClass('desc');
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      alert(col);
      var A = $(a).children('td:nth-child(' + col + ')').eq(0).text().toUpperCase();
      var B = $(b).children('td:nth-child(' + col + ')').eq(0).text().toUpperCase();

      if($.isNumeric(A) || $.isNumeric(B)) { A = parseInt(A); B = parseInt(B); }

      if(A > B) { return -1; }
      if(A < B) { return 1; }
      return 0;
    });
   } else {
    $(this).addClass('asc');
    rows.sort(function(a, b) {
      alert(col);
      var A = $(a).children('td:nth-child(' + col + ')').eq(0).text().toUpperCase();
      var B = $(b).children('td:nth-child(' + col + ')').eq(0).text().toUpperCase();

      if($.isNumeric(A) || $.isNumeric(B)) { A = parseInt(A); B = parseInt(B); }

      if(A < B) { return -1; }
      if(A > B) { return 1; }
      return 0;
    });
   }

   $(this).siblings().removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
   
   $.each(rows, function(index, row) {
     $tbody.append(row);
   });
   
   $tbody.find('tr').removeClass('visible').slice(settings.page * settings.pageCount, (settings.page + 1) * settings.pageCount).addClass('visible');
   
  });
  
  
  $tfoot.find('td').html('');
  for (var page = 0; page < numPages; page++) {
   $('<a></a>').text(page + 1).bind('click', {
    newPage: page
   }, function(event) {
    settings.page = event.data['newPage'];
    $(this).trigger('repaginate');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    if(options.pageChanged !== undefined) {
     options.pageChanged(this);
    }
   }).appendTo($tfoot); //.addClass('clickable');
  }
  
  $tbody.find('td').click(function() {
   if(options.cellClick !== undefined) {
    if($(this).hasClass('editing') == false) {
     var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
     var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent())

     var type = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-type');
     var typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values');
     var align = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-align');
     
     console.log(type);
     
     $(this).addClass('editing');
     options.cellClick(this, true, col, row);
     switch(type) {
      case 'text':
       $(this).html( '<input type="text" value="' + $(this).text() + '">' );
       $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value') );
       });
       break;
      case 'textarea':
       _html = $(this).html();
       $(this).html( '<textarea type="text">' + $(this).html().replace(/\<br\\?>/g, "\n") + '</textarea>' );
       $(this).find('textarea').focus().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value').replace(/\n/g,"<br>") );
       });
       break;      
      case 'number':
       $(this).html( '<input type="number" value="' + $(this).text() + '">' );
       $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value') );
       });
       break;
      case 'currency':
       $(this).html( '<input type="currency" value="' + $(this).text() + '">' );
       $(this).find('input').focus().blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value') );
       });
       break;
      case 'select':
       if(typevalues === undefined) {
        console.log('You must define both \'data-type\' and \'data-values\' for select elements. \'data-values\' should be a comma delimited array of the items to be displayed in the drop-down');
       } else {
        typevalues = typevalues.split(',');
        _html = '<select>';
        for(var i = 0; i < typevalues.length; i++) {
         if(typevalues[i] == $(this).text()) {
          _html = _html + '<option value="' + typevalues[i] + '" selected>' + typevalues[i] + '</option>';
         } else {
          _html = _html + '<option value="' + typevalues[i] + '">' + typevalues[i] + '</option>';
         }
        }
        _html = _html + '</select>';
        $(this).html( _html );
        $(this).find('select').focus().change(function(){
         $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
         options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
         $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value') );
        }).blur(function(){
         $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
         options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
         $(this).parent().html( $(this).prop('value') );
        });
       }
       break;
      case 'checkbox':
       if(typevalues === undefined) {
        $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values', 'T,F');
        typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values');
        console.log('You can define the \'data-values\' parameter for checkbox elements. \'data-values\' should be a comma delimited array of two items. The first item is the \'checked\' value, and the second item is the \'unchecked\' value. Defaults to \'T,F\'');
       }
       typevalues = typevalues.split(',');
       _html = '';
       if(typevalues[0] == $(this).text()) {
        _html = '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
       } else {
        _html = '<input type="checkbox">';
       }
       $(this).html( _html );
       $(this).find('input').focus().click(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values').split(',');
        if(this.checked) {
         $(this).parent().html( typevalues[0] );
        } else {
         $(this).parent().html( typevalues[1] );
        }
       })
       .blur(function(){
        $(this).parent().removeClass('editing');
        options.cellClick($(this).parent(), false, col, row);
        typevalues = $($thead.find('tr')[0].cells[col]).attr('data-values').split(',');
        if(this.checked) {
         $(this).parent().html( typevalues[0] );
        } else {
         $(this).parent().html( typevalues[1] );
        }
       });
       break;
     }
    }
   }
  })
  
  $tfoot.find('a:first-child').addClass('active');
  
  return this;
 };
}(jQuery));
```

```css
:root {
  --tables-even-color: #CDEDF7;
  --tables-odd-color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}

/* Header */
.tables > thead  > tr {
 background: #3E8096;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}

.tables > thead > tr > td {
 padding: 4px;
 padding-left: 8px;
 padding-right: 10px;
}
.tables > thead > tr > td:hover{
 background: #CDEDF7 !important;
 color: #3E8096;
}

.tables > thead > tr > td::after {
 content: " \22EF";
}

.tables > thead > tr > td.asc::after {
 content: " \22F1";
}
.tables > thead > tr > td.desc::after {
 content: " \22F0";
}

/* Footer */
.tables > tfoot  > tr {
 background: #3E8096;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}

.tables > tfoot > tr > td > a {
 border: 1px solid #3E8096;
 padding: 4px;
 cursor: pointer;
 display: inline-block;
}

.tables > tfoot > tr > td > a:hover {
 border: 1px solid #CDEDF7;
}

.tables > tfoot > tr > td > a.active {
 background: #CDEDF7;
 color: #3E8096;
}

/* Rows */
.tables > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) {
 background: #CDEDF7;
 color: #90C3D4;
}
.tables > tbody > tr:nth-child(even):hover {
 background: #18EAF5;
 color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) {
 background: #90C3D4;
 color: #CDEDF7;
}
.tables > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd):hover {
 background: #18EAF5;
 color: #90C3D4;
}

.tables > tbody > tr {
 display: none;
}

.tables > tbody > tr.visible {
 display: table-row !important;
}

.tables > tbody > tr > td {
 padding: 5px;
 cursor: default;
}

/* Cell Content */
.tables > tbody > tr > td.center {
 text-align: center;
}
.tables > tbody > tr > td.center  > input {
 text-align: center;
}
.tables > tbody > tr > td.center  > textarea {
 text-align: center;
}


.tables > tbody > tr > td.right {
 text-align: right;
}
.tables > tbody > tr > td.right  > input {
 text-align: right;
}
.tables > tbody > tr > td.right  > textarea {
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $table = $('.tables').tables( {
     pageChanged: function(item) {
      //alert(e.text());
      console.log($(item).text());
     },
     cellClick: function(item, focused, column, row) {
      //console.log('COLUMN: ' + column + ', ROW: ' + row);
     }
    });
   })
  </script>
  
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <table class="tables">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td data-type="textarea">Column 1</td>
     <td data-type="checkbox" data-align="center">Column 2</td>
<!--     <td data-type="select" data-values="Apples,Oranges,Bananas">Column 2</td> -->
    </tr>
   </thead>
   
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>aa</td>
     <td>ab</td>
    </tr>
 
    <tr>
     <td>ac</td>
     <td>ad</td>
    </tr>

    <tr><td>bb<br>ccc<b>hello</b></td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr><td>bb</td><td>bc</td></tr>
    <tr>
     <td>ac</td>
     <td>ad</td>
    </tr>    
   </tbody>
   
   <tfoot>
    <tr><td colspan="1"></td></tr>
   </tfoot>
  </table>
 </body>
</html>
```